# How can I know if the result of query is null in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a procedure with a long query and if it returns null I need to run another query but if is not null I need to return the result.
I think that I can create a temprary table but I don't want to define all columns.
Is there some way to do that in SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[your original query here]

IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
BEGIN

    [query to run if no results]
END
```